# Administer menus and menu items

Tags: routes

I've given my newly created user the permission to "Administer menus and menu items " however, when I log in as the new user I cannot administer the menus... Why might this be? The user doesn't have the permission to administer blocks, if that makes any difference?

Comment: When you say you can't administer the menus, can you describe exactly what you're trying to do?  What path are you going to, what are you expecting to see, what happens instead?  For example, if you go to the url http://www.example.com/admin/structure/menu/manage, do you actually get an access denied error?

Comment: Thank you @davidcl

I can get to /admin/structure/menu/manage without any problems. How do I display the Structure/Menu tab at the top of the page for this particular user?

Comment: I am now able to edit the menus. I gave the user permissions to Context UI and Contextual links

Comment: I'm confused-- are you saying that "Structure" doesn't show as an option in this user's toolbar?  Or that "Menu" doesn't show as an option once structure is selected?

Comment: Structure doesn't show ... @davidcl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments, I think the issue is that your user needs the "Use the administration pages and help" permission, under the System category.

Comment: Thank you. That was it! @davidcl

Is there a way to Hide the configuration tab, but keep the structure tab, for certain users?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of-- as far as I can tell once you've enabled "Use the administration pages and help" you get the Configuration tab whether you've got access to anything on it or not.

Comment: One thing you could try would be to DISABLE this permission and add links to the bottom part of the toolbar using Shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to enable the followings in `#overlay=admin/people/permissions`

```
Contextual links
Use contextual links 
Use contextual links to perform actions related to elements on a page.

Overlay 
Access the administrative overlay 
View administrative pages in the overlay.

Toolbar
Use the administration toolbar
```